# grunt-modules : feedback about pros and cons

Tags: workflow, npm, gruntjs, frontend, modular

I've crossed the path of this npm module for grunt, github.com/ozanturgut/grunt-modules, which  gives a way to make a real separation in Gruntfiles.js, making it more readable.
But I'm wondering why it isn't more encouraged as a best practices.
Any advices ?

Comment: Forgot to say where : https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-modules

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's not a best practice with Grunt. That library just adds another abstraction on top of tasks. Which means if you write a module per their specification, your module will ONLY work with their library. Thus further dividing the community.

It also creates a peer dependency to `grunt-modules` in addition to `grunt`. Peer dependencies are not easy to manage, especially if the peer author doesn't follow semver strictly. In most cases, being a peer isn't even necessary.

Using `this.data` is not recommended.

The Grunt team is moving towards a Node.js `require()` based approach. This will remove the peer dependency to grunt and allow Grunt tasks to be consumed by the entire node.js ecosystem.  The Grunt team would like to encourage other users to try and follow suit.

So just using `require()` to add helpers to your Gruntfile is the best approach now for modularizing your Gruntfile. The approach of the next version of Grunt should greatly help users better modularize their gruntfiles.